# I'm getting the value of b as 2130 can anyone explain me the process and tell me why?

Tags: java, types, integer, long-integer, short

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   byte x = 126;
    short y = 32734;
    int z = 32789;
    long a = 50000L + 10L * (x + y + z);
    System.out.println(a);

    short b = (short) (1000 + 10 * (x + y + z));
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

}

Output :
706490
2130
Why I'm getting b = 2130?

Comment: What number do you expect? And what do you know about `short`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some facts from which you can assemble the answer:

- `short` is a 16 bit signed integer type, with max value `32767`
- integer truncation occurs if overflowing with narrowing cast
- `1000 + 10 * (126 + 32734 + 32789)` is `657490`
- `657490 % 32768` is `2130`

Answer (score -1):

Reason is java Narrowing or Explicit Conversion.  [Refer this *](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-java-examples/)